# Display (in the terminal) a 72 column text field

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I'm looking for a way to display a text field (probably surrounded by asterisks or something) that is 72 columns wide that the user can type in. I would like to run the script, and at one point set the value of a variable to what this text field returns, newlines included. They would exit text entry with some key sequence or a line with one word, the sentinal value, followed by the enter key. Upon exciting, the variable contains the text, including newlines.

I currently can capture the text using `$(cat)` or a simple `read` loop, but I'm looking for an an alternative, or a way to restrict lines to 72 and keep newlines using those methods.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `ncurses` or similar cli widgeting system? Possibly something like `dialog` so you can drive it from a normal shell script?

Comment: @EtanReisner `dialog` was my first intention too. However, on Ubuntu 14.04 it fails with segfault when displaying an `--editbox` (for multiline input) . This should not happen. I'm not sure, but the program is looking orphaned.

Comment: Perhaps try `whiptail` instead?

Comment: I ended up going with `dialog` using the `--editbox` option after creating a temporary text file. Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with `dialog` using the `--editbox` option after creating a temporary text file. Thank you for the suggestions –  broma0